# Regex for extracting names starting with Mr.|Mrs|The|DR after honorable

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to write regex for identifying name starting with MR|MS|THE|DR after honorable

for example

```
      HONOURABLE THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE
 1    VIKRAM NATH,HONOURABLE MR. JUSTICE             1     1      0     3       5
      J.B.PARDIWALA
      HONOURABLE THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE
 2    VIKRAM NATH,HONOURABLE MR. JUSTICE VIPUL M.    0     1      0     0       1
      PANCHOLI
      HONOURABLE THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE
 3    VIKRAM NATH,HONOURABLE MR. JUSTICE ASHUTOSH   107    4     10     6      127
      J. SHASTRI
```

So, the output should be

```
[THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE VIKRAM NATH, MR. JUSTICE J.B.PARDIWALA]
[THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE VIKRAM NATH, MR. JUSTICE VIPUL M. PANCHOLI]
and so on
```

but I'm getting

```
THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE VIKRAM NATH 
MR. JUSTICE             1     1      0     3       5
      J.B.PARDIWALA
```

I have tried `\s*HONOURABLE\s+(?=THE|MR|MS|DR)([^/\[\]\n]*)`

HONOURABLE can be repeated any no. of times.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the problem with your solution?

Comment: Sounds like you want `re.findall(r'\bHONOURABLE\s+((?:THE|MRS?|MS|DR)\b[^,]*)', text)`

Comment: `\bHONOURABLE\s+((?:THE\s+|(?:M[RS]|DR)\.)[^][/\n,]*)` https://regex101.com/r/TA9NJ2/1

Comment: Hi, I see you unaccepted the answer, do you need more specific help with this?

Comment: Yes, I'm new to regex. Can you help me to exclude numbers from the output.

Comment: Ok, but you do not have to unaccept the answer since it was correct before your update. It is not welcomed on SO. If you have a new question, just ask a new question, do not say "Current answers are outdated" as it just means you have a new question.

Comment: I have updated my current answer.

Answer (score 10):

**Bounty answer**

You can use

```py
import re
text = """     HONOURABLE THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE
 1    VIKRAM NATH,HONOURABLE MR. JUSTICE             1     1      0     3       5
      J.B.PARDIWALA
      HONOURABLE THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE
 2    VIKRAM NATH,HONOURABLE MR. JUSTICE VIPUL M.    0     1      0     0       1
      PANCHOLI
      HONOURABLE THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE
 3    VIKRAM NATH,HONOURABLE MR. JUSTICE ASHUTOSH   107    4     10     6      127
      J. SHASTRI"""
text = re.sub(r'^[\d \t]+|[\d \t]+$', '', text, flags=re.M)
#print(text)
m = re.findall(r'^HONOURABLE\s+(.*(?:\n(?!HONOURABLE\b).*)*)', text, re.M)
for x in m:
    print(x.replace('\n',' '))
```

Output:

```
[
  'THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE VIKRAM NATH,HONOURABLE MR. JUSTICE J.B.PARDIWALA',
  'THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE VIKRAM NATH,HONOURABLE MR. JUSTICE VIPUL M. PANCHOLI',
  'THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE VIKRAM NATH,HONOURABLE MR. JUSTICE ASHUTOSH J. SHASTRI'
]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fAjgsw).

**Details**:

- `re.sub(r'^[\d \t]+|[\d \t]+$', '', text, flags=re.M)` removes all spaces, tabs and digits from the start and end of each line in your text.
- `r'^HONOURABLE\s+(.*(?:\n(?!HONOURABLE\b).*)*)'` is a regex that matches the following in the "trimmed" text:
- `^` - start of a line
- `HONOURABLE` - a word `HONOURABLE`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(.*(?:\n(?!HONOURABLE\b).*)*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\n(?!HONOURABLE\b).*)*` - zero or more lines that do not start with `HONOURABLE` as a whole word.

**Original answer**
You can use

```py
\bHONOURABLE\s+((?:THE|MR|MS|DR)[^,]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XJos8r/1). If you do not want to have linebreaks in the resulting list items, you may later replace them with `.replace('\n', ' ')`. If you want to curb the right hand boundary of your matches at `[`, `\` and `]`, add them to the negated character class, change `[^,]` to `[^][/,]`.

*Details*:

- `\bHONOURABLE` - a whole word `HONOURABLE`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `((?:THE|MR|MS|DR)[^,]*)` - Capturing group 1: `THE`, `MR`, `MS`, `DR` followed with zero or more chars other than a comma.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/rUF7Jr):

```py
import re
rx = r"\bHONOURABLE\s+((?:THE|MR|MS|DR)\b[^,]*)"
text = "HONOURABLE THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE\nVIKRAM NATH,HONOURABLE MR. JUSTICE ASHUTOSH\nJ. SHASTRI, HONOURABLE MS. ADITI GUPTA"
m = re.findall(rx, text)
print([x.replace('\n','') for x in m])
```

Output:

```py
['THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICEVIKRAM NATH', 'MR. JUSTICE ASHUTOSHJ. SHASTRI', 'MS. ADITI GUPTA']
```

Comment: A problem that will happen with your solution is:
`HONOURABLE THE CHIEF JUSTICE MR. JUSTICE VIKRAM NATH,\n
 1    HONOURABLE MR. JUSTICE             1     1      0     3       5\n
      J.B.PARDIWALA`
In this case, you will break this paragraph into 2 arrays, because it has two lines that start with HONOURABLE.

Comment: @AndreMarasca This is one approach that works for the current OP data. If OP confirms the contents are different, then there must be some other criterion that would help define match boundaries.